# Why is appending to a list not working?

Tags: python

```
>>> alist = [["H"]]
>>> mylist = alist[0].append([2])
>>> print(mylist)
>>>
```

As you can see it prints nothing. 
I'm trying to get this as the result.

```
>>> [["H", [2]]]
```

Any help?

Comment: It should've printed `None`. Did you actually `print`, or did you just say `mylist`?

Comment: `alist[0].append([2])` actually appends `[2]` to `alist`. It returns `None`. If you check `alist` it should have `['H', [2]]`...

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` actually appends to the existing list, it does not return a new list:

```
alist = [["H"]]
alist[0].append(2)
print( alist )
```

Comment: append actually appends to the existing list, it does not return a new list